# How to edit Dataset?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, datasnap

### Short Version

How do i call:

```
dataset1.FieldByName(fieldName).AsString := 'Something';
```

and have it work?

### Long version

I have a `DataSet`:

```
var
    ds: TDataSet;

    ds := GetSomeSortOfDataSetFromSomewhere();
```

This dataset will be exported (e.g. to Excel, cSV, TSV, Markdown, HTML, XML):

```
ExportDataSet(ds);
```

and the export will contain all columns and all rows:

| Username | Fullname |
| --- | --- |
| ian | IAN BOYD |
| MartynA | MARTIN |
| ngal | NASREDDINE GALFOUT |
| uewr | UWE RAABE |

Now i want to modify the `Fullname` field for each row *in-memory* before doing something else with it (i.e. it's never going back into a database, i don't know where it came from , it might not have come from a database):

```
while not ds.EOF do
begin
    ds.FieldByName('Fullname').AsString := FormatNamePrettyLike(ds.FieldByName('Fullname').AsString;
    ds.Next;
end;
```

Trying to modify a field gives the exception:

> [Dataset not in edit or insert mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48314436/12597)

The solution is to *clone* the dataset into an in-memory [`TClientDataset`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet):

```
///<summary>Clones a dataset into a TClientDataSet; which is an editable in-memory DataSet.</summary>
function CloneDataSet(dsSource: TDataSet): TDataSet; //TDataSet > TCustomClientDataSet > TClientDataSet
var
    tempProvider: TDataSetProvider;
    data: OleVariant;
    ds: TClientDataSet;
begin
    tempProvider := TDataSetProvider.Create(nil);
    try
        tempProvider.DataSet := dsSource;
        data := tempProvider.Data;
    finally
        tempProvider.Free;
    end;

    ds := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
    ds.Data := data;

    Result := ds;
end;
```

Which gives larger code:

```
var
   ds: TDataset;
   dsEditable: TDataSet;

   ds := GetDataSomeOfSomeSortFromSomewhere();

   //Clone to dataset to an in-memory dataset so we can modify it.
   dsEditable := CloneDataSet(ds);
   ds.Free;
   ds := edEditable;

   while not ds.EOF do
   begin
       ds.FieldByName('Fullname').AsString := FormatNamePrettyLike(ds.FieldByName('Fullname').AsString;
       ds.Next;
    end;
```

But this gives the error:

> [Dataset not in edit or insert mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48314436/12597)

The solution is to [put the dataset in edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17334907/12597):

```
//The in-memory ClientDataSet won't be editable until you mark it editable.
ds.Edit;
```

```
///<summary>Clones a dataset into a TClientDataSet; which is an editable in-memory DataSet.</summary>
function CloneDataSet(dsSource: TDataSet): TDataSet; //TDataSet > TCustomClientDataSet > TClientDataSet
var
    tempProvider: TDataSetProvider;
    data: OleVariant;
    ds: TClientDataSet;
begin
    tempProvider := TDataSetProvider.Create(nil);
    try
        tempProvider.DataSet := dsSource;
        data := tempProvider.Data;
    finally
        tempProvider.Free;
    end;

    ds := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
    ds.Data := data;

    //The in-memory ClientDataSet won't be editable until you mark it editable.
    ds.Edit;

    Result := ds;
end;
```

Repeating the excerise now gives the error:

> Field `Fullname` cannot be modified.

The solution is to [set Field.ReadOnly to false](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=109328):

```
//Even after marking the in-memory data-set as editable, you still can't edit it 
//until you mark all fields as editable.
for i := 0 to ds.FieldCount-1 do
   ds.Fields[i].ReadOnly := False;
```

```
///<summary>Clones a dataset into a TClientDataSet; which is an editable in-memory DataSet.</summary>
function CloneDataSet(dsSource: TDataSet): TDataSet; //TDataSet > TCustomClientDataSet > TClientDataSet
var
    tempProvider: TDataSetProvider;
    data: OleVariant;
    ds: TClientDataSet;
begin
    tempProvider := TDataSetProvider.Create(nil);
    try
        tempProvider.DataSet := dsSource;
        data := tempProvider.Data;
    finally
        tempProvider.Free;
    end;

    ds := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
    ds.Data := data;

    //The in-memory ClientDataSet won't be editable until you mark it editable.
    ds.Edit;

    //Even after marking the in-memory data-set as editable, you still can't edit it 
    //until you mark all fields as editable.
    for i := 0 to ds.FieldCount-1 do
        ds.Fields[i].ReadOnly := False;

    Result := ds;
end;
```

Repeating the exercise gives the error:

> Trying to modify read-only field.

So i give up. How do i edit a DataSet field?

The cloned in-memory TCustomClientDataSet contents are all there; i just want to edit them on the client for display purposes.

### Bonus Chatter

Obviously i can't be adding new columns to the data set:

| Username | Fullname | PrettyFullname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ian | IAN BOYD | Ian Boyd |
| MartynA | MARTIN | Martin |
| ngal | NASREDDINE GALFOUT | Nasreddine Galfout |
| uewr | UWE RAABE | Uwe Raabe |

Obviously i can't attach an event handler to the data set:

- as that data handler would be invalid when the data set is passed onto the next person in a chain (e.g. a thread), and the original form is freed
- and it's also not what i'm asking; which is about modifying the contents of a data set
- the updating of values hits other systems (e.g. databases, web-services, etc). I want the changes done once, and then **in** the data set

Comment: You should call DataSet.Edit to place the dataset into dsEdit state before trying to modify fields and DataSet.Post afterwards to post the change(s) to the current record back to the dataset before moving to the next one.  Actually, moving the dataset cursor (by calling Next, Prior, First, etc) will implicitly post any pending changes but it is best not to rely on this.  It would be better to use DSP and CDS components on your form/datamodule as it will likely be easier to locate your problems. Editing data in a CDS should "just work" unless [cont]

Comment: your DSP is getting its data from a read-only source.  In your position I would boil the thing down to a minimal example and debug that - it really shouldn't take more than about 10 lines of code, rather than the screeds you seem to have atm.  Btw, if the DSP source is a Sql dataset, the DSP is smart enough to generate the code for emitting UPDATE statements to enforce the changes even if the source is nominally a read-only query result.

Comment: PS Don't forget to call ApplyUpdates on the CDS otherwise they won't be.

Comment: @MartynA that is not what OP is asking. He said the names will not be posted to the database. He wants to modify them for show.

Comment: Did you try calling `Ds.Edit` before `ds.FieldByName('Fullname').AsString` after cloning the dataset?

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout:  Well, I imagine the OP (whose research is uually meticulous) is aware that the on-screen names of fields can be changed using TField's DisplayLabel property.

Comment: @MartynA I had the same assumption. But who knows will have to wait and see his response.

Comment: Calculated fields are used for this.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz So you cannot modify the values of an in-memory TClientDataSet? In this case i'm using a TClientDataSet as one-step above a two-dimensional array.

Comment: I think the point @Sertac is making it that if you just want to have a prettified presentation of the `FullName` for display purposes, simplify add an fkInternalCalc field to the CDS and format its value as you want in the `OnCalcFields` event - then, there is no need to traverse the CDS at all in code, it is all done behind the scenes.  But of course it's **possible** to edit the records in a CDS, that's the whole point of them.  And the DSP provides a way of feeding back changes to the underlying dataset **even** if it was obtained from a SQL query which gave a read-only result set.

Comment: @MartynA *"But of course it's **possible** to edit the records in a CDS, that's the whole point of them."* Excellent; how do i do that?

Comment: I'll post a demo in about 5 minutes.  Watch this space.

Comment: If I understand your edit correctly, just follow the example in my answer and omit the call to ApplyUpdates.  But I'm not sure I follow your ruling out of using an added fkInternalCalc field instead, because the CDS's data could be passed to any downstream use of it.  And you could easily remove it when passing the CDS data downstream.  Oh, and you can certainly add an OnCalcFields handler.

Comment: My concern with adding an event handler is that there how has to be an event handler - which risks an access violation when the form/object holding the event handler is destroyed. I'm also concerned that the next person would see new fields, rather than just the existing fields. My **question** is how to alter the existing values, in-place, in-memory, in a data set. I was under the impression that an in-memory `TClientDataSet` was in-memory - which led to me assume that the values could be altered in-memory.

Comment: Sorry, you are fundamentally misunderstanding how CDS's work, istm.  They **are** in-memory datasets, and if you follow my example and omit the ApplyUpdates they stay in memory.  Part of the "magic" of CDSs is that the data is entirely contained in the `Data` property, an OLEVariant and this can be passed along a chain of CDSs in a "pass the parcel" fashion.  It's difficult to imagine it being any simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I actually understand your question correctly, it boils down to change the field content of *FullName* to some pretty formatted string for display.

So as you don't want to change the actual field content, the best place to do this is in the fields *OnGetText* event. A proper event handler for your task could look like this:

```
procedure TMyClass.MakeFullNamePrettyGetText(Sender: TField; var Text: string; DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  Text := FormatNamePrettyLike(Sender.AsString);
end;
```

Now you have to wire that event handler to the field. As you are working with dynamic fields this has to be done each time after opening the dataset:

```
qry.FieldByName('Fullname').OnGetText := MakeFullNamePrettyGetText;
```

As long as this happens outside of the class the event is declared in, you need to prefix the event name with a class instance of *TMyClass* (or whatever you may call it).

Answer (score 1):

Below is a completely self-contained example of edting data from a Sql Server
using ADO + a TClientDataSet. All the components are simply dropped from the palette
onto the form and then all necessary properties are set up in code in the `SetUp` procedure.

At each step, I've tried to use the simplest code to do the job so as not to obscure
the elegant simplicity of how the CDS + TDataSetProvider work to edit data.  See the `TSqlResolver.GenUpdateSql` method in Provider.Pas to see how 
it generates the necessary Sql UPDATE statements for the DSP to emit to update
the data in the server table.  These are sent to the server via a special type
of datapacket which the DSP uses to communicate between its CDS and source dataset.

Hopefully the code is self-explanatory with minimal comments.

As you will see, absolutely no fiddling with the attributes of the CDS's TFields
is necessary.  Btw, I have done this as a VCL app rather than a console one simply 
so that it's trivial to visually confirm that everything is working.

As a kind of lowest common denominator I've used D7.  In post-Unicode Delphi,
the FullName field on the server would be an NVarChar type and the string field type
of the CDS would adjust automatically.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    CDS1: TClientDataSet;
    DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure SetUp;
  end;
[...]
const
  scConnString = 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=MATest;Data Source=MAT430\ss2014';
  scCreateTable = 'create table TestTable(ID int not null primary key, FullName varchar(40))';
  scSelectAll = 'select * from TestTable';

procedure TForm1.SetUp;
begin
  AdoConnection1.ConnectionString := scConnString;

{.$define CreateTable}  // to do a one-off creation of the server table and data
{$ifdef CreateTable}
  AdoConnection1.Execute(scCreateTable);
{$endif}

  AdoQuery1.Connection := AdoConnection1;
  AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := scSelectAll;

{$ifdef CreateTable}
  AdoQuery1.Open;
  AdoQuery1.InsertRecord([1, 'Joe Blow']);
  AdoQuery1.Close;                             
{$endif}

  DataSetProvider1.DataSet := AdoQuery1;
  CDS1.ProviderName := 'DataSetProvider1';
  DataSource1.DataSet := CDS1;
  DBGrid1.DataSource := DataSource1;

  CDS1.Open;
  CDS1.Edit;
  CDS1.FieldByName('FullName').AsString := 'Mr ' + CDS1.FieldByName('FullName').AsString;
  CDS1.Post;

  //  Post the chamges back to the server table if desired
  CDS1.ApplyUpdates(0);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetUp;
end;

end.
```

**Addendum**  One point which was raised in comments was the possibility of effectivel prettifying the FullName field by using a calculated field.  I can't immediately think of a way to set this up in code
but basicially I would do this:

- On the CDS, set up persistent TFields  (from the CDS's context menu).
- In the Fields editor, add a calculated field of type fkInternalCalc.  For a CDS, this
  is better to use than fkCalculated because an fkInternalCalc can be included in an index on the CDS
- Do whatever calculation is necessary in the CDS's `OnCalcFields` event.  No traversal
  (in your code) of the CDS records is then necessary to do the calculations because the CDS does the calculations in its own machinations.

**Update**  It turns out that it is straightforward, if a bit of a rigmarole, to add an fkInternal calc field to a CDS entirely in code.  The trick is to retrieve the FieldDefs from the server, persist them in the CDS and then re-create its TFields and re-open it.  Like so:

```
  CDS1.Open;
  CDS1.StoreDefs := True;
  CDS1.Close;
  for i := 0 to CDS1.FieldDefs.Count - 1 do begin
    Field := CDS1.FieldDefs[i].CreateField(Self, Nil, CDS1.FieldDefs[i].DisplayName);
  end;
  Field := TStringField.Create(Self);
  Field.Size := CDS1.FieldByName('FullName').Size;
  Field.FieldKind := fkInternalCalc;
  Field.FieldName := 'EnhFullName';
  Field.DataSet := CDS1;

  CDS1.Open;
```

Comment: Can you try closing and freeing your database connection (`AdoConnection1`) after you initially query for the data. Also close and free your ADOQuery (`AdoQuery`). It seems that some operations silently try to update the data back in the data source. Completely destroying the databae connection will remove any possiblity of the data being updated back anywhere.

Comment: I don't think I need to:  Simply setting the DSP's `DataSet` property to Nil should disconnect it from the AdoQuery and thus remove any possibility of the changes being sent back to the server.  Or you could simply do CDS2.Data := CDS1.Data (CDS2 being a free-standing one with no DSP whatever) and then do your work on CDS2.

Comment: Oh, and I hope it goes without saying that if you wanted to preserve a copy of CDS1's data prior to any edits, you coulf simply do CDS2.Data := CDS1.Data before doing the edits.  Btw, no initialization of CDS2 would be necessary before it would pick up all the field definitions, etc in the Midas datapack contained in CDS1.Data;